# Bard Focused Sound Criticals

Tags: dnd-4e, bard

In Arcane Power the Bard lvl 1 Encounter Power Focused Sound says:

> Until the end of your next turn, any attack against the target can score a critical hit on a roll of 18-20.

Does this mean that every attack made against the target is a crit on 18-20, or only 1?

If it is only 1 attack how do you determine which attack it is? It says *any* not first, theoretically if it really is just 1 of any 18-20 on the target then you don't have to choose the first one and save the choice of which one for whom ever would do the most damage.

Personally, I think it would be all attacks against the target that score a 18-20 on the attack roll would be critical hits.

Comment: 4e rules should always be taken at face value and refer when necessary to keyword definitions in the rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means *any* attack through the end of your next turn *can* score a crit on a roll of 18-20.

There are a few variations of this phrasing for you to compare:

- Until the end of your next turn, the *next/first* attack...
- Until the end of your next turn, *any* attack...
- Until the end of your next turn *any* attack you make...

Those are the typical ones. As you can see the phrasing in your power is in contrast to the "next" attack language. It's also in contrast to the third phrasing which applies only to *your* attacks.

This power enables both you and your allies towards more expansive criticals.